# Python- struggling with lists

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and really struggling with this assignment.

I got data in the following format

```
ID  M  R ###
1 1193 5 978300763
2 1193 3 978299712
2 1953 4 978298775
3 1193 3 978300025.....
```

Now i've to find pairs of IDs for whom 'M' is the same.
since M is the same for 1,2 and 3.

the output should be [1,2],[1,3] and [2,3]

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the problem is, and it would be useful if you presented what you've tried so far and which step you specifically need help with

Comment: please try to make your question clear with the way you progressed.

Comment: sorry, i'll make it clear

Comment: ok. i'll make another post and explain what i've done

Comment: @Dave_30 Just edit it into this question. You don't need to make another post

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> data = '''ID  M  R ###
1 1193 5 978300763
2 1193 3 978299712
2 1953 4 978298775
3 1193 3 978300025'''

>>> data = [line.split() for line in data.splitlines()[1:]]
>>> from itertools import groupby, combinations
>>> key = lambda x: x[1]
>>> for k, g in groupby(sorted(data, key=key), key):
        print(k, list(combinations(map(lambda x: x[0], g), 2)))

1193 [('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('2', '3')]
1953 []
```